# Running python code through Cython with command line arguments

Tags: python, c, command-line-arguments, cython

I have a Python code that uses two command line arguments. I am using linux terminal for all command line tasks. Now I am trying to use Cython to speed up my Python code. 
For that I have compiled the Python code to C using build_ext module by creating this setup.py file:

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
setup (
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext } ,
ext_modules = [
Extension ("myCode", ["myCode.py"]) ,
])
```

And then compiling my Python code into C using:

```
python setup.py build_ext -i
```

The following were generated:

```
[file]myCode.c
[file]myCode.so
[folder]build
--[folder]temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
----[file]myCode.o
```

I want to run the generated file with command line arguments.
Till now in Python I was using the usual command

```
>> python myCode.py arg1 arg2
```

I am very new to Cython, infact I started using it to address the inherent speed issue of Python after code level algorithm optimization. I need inputs on which files to run, and how to run the converted C code and with command line arguments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After Cython compiled it `myCode.so` becomes a module. You cannot run it, you have to import it: `python -c 'import myCode'`.

Comment: @phd where should I place this line exactly and in which file? Once I place it properly, I will get to understand its purpose.

Comment: It was only an example. `myCode` is a module, you have to import it as any other module. It's just not .py module but compiled .so.

Comment: I understand that. But do I have to import it in my original Python code (myCode.py)? If yes, what is that I have to do to use this imported module? Another thing, myCode.c have any manual use?

Comment: You cannot import it back into myCode.py: myCode.py nad myCode.so are the same module, just a source code and compiled form. You haven't show us myCode.py so how can we guess what's there? Usually one puts functions and classes into a module, compiles it and import those functions/classes into a program. I.e. you have to have a program to import `myCode` into.

Comment: Oh, I see where is your problem: Cython should be used to compile **modules**, not **programs**! `myCode.py` must be a moule imported from a program and when you compile it your program imports .so instead of .py.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for clearing up this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

as [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) commented: "You cannot run it, you have to import it"

`python -c 'import myCode'`

after compiling `myCode.pyx` you'll have `myCode.so` and in another script you import that as normal

```py
# other_script.py
import myCode
```

then
`python other_script.py` in a terminal

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you compiled a Python module.  So to call from Linux you have to write a `.py` script that imports your compiled module and does any calculations needed.  Then you can run it with your typical Linux command.